# ¿identificar elementos en combobox en c# y xaml?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Tengo este combobox en XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Tempos" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              Height="55" 
              Margin="90,216,0,0" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              Width="205" SelectionChanged="Tempos_SelectionChanged" >
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2/4" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="3/4" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="4/4" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="5/4" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="6/4" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="7/4" />
    </ComboBox>
```

Y en C# tengo este método:

```
private void Tempos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        resultado.text= Tempos.SelectedIndex.ToString();

    }
```

Estoy ocupando `selectedindex` pero eso sirve si se sabe siempre el orden, pero si es dinamico el orden de los campos en mi `ComboBox` como los identidico?

Comment: No se a que te refieres por dinámico, pero la propiedad `SelectedIndex` te retorna la posición _(en base cero)_ del elemento seleccionado en el `ComboBox`, no hay un orden, dado que todos los elementos tienen su indice asignado y si "dinamicamente" cargas los campos, debe de funcionar de igual forma.

Answer (score 1):

Si necesitas un identificador para cada item del combo deberias asignarlo usando el `SelectedValuePath` el tema es que para poder asignarlo deberias indicar un origen de datos

[WPF ComboBox and DataBinding: DataContext, ItemsSource, DisplayMemberPath, SelectedItem, SelectedValue & SelectedValuePath](http://blog.cylewitruk.com/2010/09/wpf-combobox-and-databinding-datacontext-itemssource-displaymemberpath-selecteditem-selectedvalue-selectedvaluepath/)

la idea es que definas una clase, por ejemplo

```
public class Country
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Id{ get; set; }
}
```

y puedas indicarlo en el control

```
<ComboBox
   ItemsSource="{Binding Countries, Mode=OneWay}"
   DisplayMemberPath="Name"
   SelectedValue="{Binding ...}"
   SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```

al asignar el ItemsSource la propiedad Countries que seria una `List<Country>` puedes indicar propiedades que definen el Value de cada elemento, entonces podrias usar el `SelectedValue` para tomar el valor que identifica al elemento en la lista sin importar el orden en que se carguen

Answer (score 0):

Deberías cargar un id para poder identificarlos, pero también podes obtener el valor del ítem seleccionado de la siguiente manera:

```
string value = Tempos.SelectedValue.ToString();
resultado.text = "Selected: " + value ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el elemento seleccionado en el comboBox en C# sugiero esto :

```
private void Tempos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       resultado.text= Tempos.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

*No confundas el Index (índice) con el Item (elemento). El índice es la posición de un elemento, empezando por 0. El elemento (Item), es el objeto en la colección de objetos.*